# $\log^2 (n)$ Vs. $n^\frac{1 }{ 80}$ asymptotically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I have been trying to figure out which term is "asymptotically" greater.

> $f(n) = \log^2 (n)$  and $g(n)  = n^\frac{1 }{ 80}$

I took the limit as ${n\to\infty}$ of $\frac{f(n) }{ g(n)}$, and I concluded that   $n^\frac{1 }{ 80}$ is asymptotically greater.

$n>0$

1) Am I right?

2) If I replace the number 80 with a greater integer would that change the answer?

3) If I replace the power of log with a greater integer, would that change the answer?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) No. 3) No.

Comment: To the second and third questions: it would only make it take longer (i.e. for even larger $n$) for the dominating to occur. For example we have that
$$\log^{10}(n) < n^{1/100}$$
approximately when $n> 7.9\cdot 10^{3959}$, a crazy large number! (According to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(n)%5E10+%3C+n%5E(1%2F100.0))).

Comment: Thanks everyone.You guys are really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes you are right.

2,3) No, it would not.

Let $f_k(x)=\log^kx$, $g_m(x)=x^{\frac{1}{m}}$ for $k\geq 1$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $m>0$. Then

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f_k(x)}{g_m(x)} &= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{k\log^{k-1}(x)\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{m}x^{\frac{1-m}{m}}}\\
&= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}mk\frac{\log^{k-1}(x)}{x^{\frac{1}{m}}}\\
&= mk\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f_{k-1}(x)}{g_m(x)}
\end{align*}

Since we know that for $k=1$ we have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_m(x)}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{\frac{1}{m}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{m}x^{\frac{1-m}{m}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}m\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{m}}}\\
&=0
\end{align*}

we can conclude that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f_k(x)}{g_m(x)}=0$ for all $k\geq 1$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $m>0$.

In case you are wondering, I used l'Hopitals rule in the first step each time.

The assumptions $k\geq 1$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ was made for simplicity, I believe it should be true for all $k\in\mathbb{R}$.